# A slight anomaly in a question regarding real numbers

Tags: proof-writing, contest-math, real-numbers

> The leftmost digit of the decimal representations of the natural
> numbers $2^n$ and $5^n$ is the same. Prove that such digit is equal to $3$.

I wanted to see some pattern in the given question(so as to get the feel of the problem) so I used my programming knowledge(as far it is taught in school).
Here is it:

```
public class blackadd 
{
    public static void main()
    {int m,n;
        int h=0,l=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
        {n=(int)Math.pow(2,i);
            m=(int)Math.pow(5,i);
            while(n!=0)
            {h=n%10;
                n=n/10;
            
        }
               System.out.println("for 2   :"+h); 
                while(m!=0)
            {l=m%10;
                m=m/10;
            
        }
               System.out.println("for 5  :"+l+"\n"+"-------");   
            if(l==h)
            System.out.println(i);
           
        }}}
```

The anomalous output obtained is:

```
for 2   :2
for 5  :2
-------
28
```

where $28$ is $n$ in the question. I could not figure out what is wrong with my program. Please let me know. Further, How can I prove this if it is true?Slight hint would do good.

Comment: Am I missing something? For $n = 1$, the leftmost digits are $2$ and $5$. $n = 2$: $4$ and $5$. $n = 3$: $8$ and $1$. They are not equal?

Comment: I think what it means is that **when** it's equal, it's a 3.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinArgerami.

Comment: My pocket calculator tells me $2^{28}$ and $5^{28}$ have different leading digits (2 and 3 respectively). A rough heuristics which you probably have to make more precise is this. The product of $2^n$ and $5^n$ is $10^n$ which has leading digit $1$. The only possibility is that both of the leading digits are $3$ so you get $3\times 3\approx 10$ or you get $1$ and the leading digit is $\approx 1$.

Comment: I think the "error" in your code stems from integer overflow. As @daruma has pointed out, $2^{28}$ and $\color{red}{5}^{28}$ have different leading digits.

Comment: I don't know about integer overflow. What is it?

Comment: Essentially Java cannot handle integers bigger than a certain limit. So then it wraps back and gives the wrong answer. (Basically, the integers in Java are just integers modulo $N$ for some  "big" $N$.)

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: You can use logarithms to determine the first digit much more accurately.

Comment: All the primitive numeric data types in Java (such as `int`) have strictly defined limits. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

Comment: @daruma I hesitate to post this, because surely I must be missing something, but it seems to me that that *is* a proof. A leading digit of $1$ for both $2^n$ and $5^n$ could not give the product $10^n,$ so $3$ *is* the only possibility. (Even when I write out the inequalities carefully, using a variable letter for the common leading digit of $2^n$ and $5^n,$ this conclusion still seems to hold.) I'll get me coat. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tiny bit of numerical experimentation gives me that the first few $n$ where the first digit of $2^n$ is equal to the first digit of $5^n$ are
$$
5,15,78,88,98,108,118,181,191,201,211,274,284,294,304.
$$
In all cases such first digit is a 3. I don't know how to prove the general fact, though. It looks like one should exploit the fact that $2^n5^n=10^n$, but since every digit is possible, it is not obvious to me how to approach a proof.

As for your program, you are using `math.pow`, which uses double arithmetic, and casting to an `int`. This makes your program start to fail when `i=14`. That's when $5^{14}=6,103,515,625$, which is already greater than the highest possible `int` which is $2,147,483,647$. What Java is doing (which I personally don't think is very nice) is just give you back $2,147,483,647$; that's why your program is incorrectly giving every single first digit for $5^n$, $n\geq14$, as $2$. Here is your program modified to work with double

```
public class blackadd 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {double m,n;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int h=0,l=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=440;i++)
        {n= Math.pow(2,i);
            m= Math.pow(5,i);
            while(n>=1)
            {h=(int)(n - 10 * Math.floor(n / 10));
                n=n/10;
            
        }
                while(m>=1)
            {l=(int)(m - 10 * Math.floor(m / 10));
                m=m/10;
            
        }
               System.out.println(i+":   "+h+" --  "+l);   
            if(l==h)
                System.out.println("\n"+"-------"+i);
           
        }
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
        System.out.println(totalTime);    
    }
    
}
```

This should work fine until $n=541$, more or less, which is where $5^n$ reaches the greatest number than can be expressed as a double. Note that `%` does not work with doubles, so I had to change the way to calculate the digits. I run the program up to $i=440$ because beyond that the platform I was using (*codingground*) failed; not sure if it is a Java or platform thing.

As a general comment, you would usually not want to use `Math.pow` to calculate powers of integers, in particular when you are using all the powers through a loop like here. You can initialize `n=1` and multiply it by 2 on every iteration. I didn't put this in the code because in this case to extract the digit from a double is harder than to extract the digit from an integer as you are doing. For a double the best way I know is to do

`h = Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10,Math.floor(Math.log10(n))))`,

which is not particularly efficient with four calls to the Math library.